# transpose list of lists - empty output, python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to transpose a list of lists I made. I made the list of lists by appending lists to one another: I have four lists of ten items each.

This is my list of lists.
`[['Bin1', 'Bin2', 'Bin3', 'Bin4', 'Bin5', 'Bin6', 'Bin7', 'Bin8', 'Bin9', 'Bin10'], ['TTF is greater than or equal to 50.0,', 'TTF is greater than or equal to 88.0,', 'TTF is greater than or equal to 126.0,', 'TTF is greater than or equal to 164.0,', 'TTF is greater than or equal to 202.0,', 'TTF is greater than or equal to 240.0,', 'TTF is greater than or equal to 278.0,', 'TTF is greater than or equal to 316.0,', 'TTF is greater than or equal to 354.0,'], ['less than 88.0:', 'less than 126.0:', 'less than 164.0:', 'less than 202.0:', 'less than 240.0:', 'less than 278.0:', 'less than 316.0:', 'less than 354.0:', 'less than or equal to 430.0:'], [17, 29, 25, 9, 8, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2]]`

I used this code to try and transpose the list of lists but it did not work.

```
def transpose(lst):
    newlist = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        j = 0
        colvec = []
        while j < len(lst):
            colvec.append(lst[j][i])
            j = j + 1
        newlist.append(colvec)
        i = i + 1
    return newlist
```

This code just returns a pair of empty brackets `[]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your code works when input is `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. what the actual input you tried? also, range of `i` and `j`  is both `0` to `len(lst)`, it may give index out of bounds exception when input is `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`.

Comment: Have edited main question

Comment: I tried your code with the same input of yours. but the output is not empty `[]`. how did you check that output is empty?

Comment: Your data is not uniform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
def transpose(a):
  r = len(a)
  c = len(a[0])
  print(r,c)
  b = []
  for i in range(c):
    b.append([0]*r)
  for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
      b[j][i] = a[i][j]
  print(b)
```

I suggest using [numpy.ndarray.T](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy-ndarray-t):

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([[5, 4],[1, 2]])
print(a)
print(a.T)
```

Output:

```
[[5 4]
 [1 2]]
[[5 1]
 [4 2]]
```

Comment: This does not work, all it does is put more brackets around my list of lists: `[[[ ['Bin1', 'Bin2', 'Bin3', 'Bin4', 'Bin5', 'Bin6', 'Bin7', 'Bin8', 'Bin9', 'Bin10']]]` e.g. this is now the first list

Comment: Can you edit the list in your answer to be more readable so I can try it?

Comment: `a = np.array(array)
print (a)
print(a.T)` I use this code. My output is exactly the same as the list of lists I wrote in my question. `array` in my code here refers to my list of lists.

Comment: the number of columns in your data is not uniform for every row

Comment: I have edited my data so it is all equal length, thank you. I now get this error when trying out your first solution:  
    `b[j][i] = a[i][j]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I've tested my solution thoroughly. I suggest you to verify your data again. I have a working sample here: https://repl.it/@stupidlylogical/BasicTranspose